# mySQL seeing if row exist

Tags: mysql, exists

Hey all i have the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT * " .
            "FROM wp_postmeta " .
            "WHERE post_id = " . $postID . " " .
            "AND meta_key = 'xTraData';";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo $result;
    echo '    ' . $postID;

if($result >= 1){
```

And i am returned **Resource id #2** for the **$result**....

[image]

There are no rows for that. Its all *null* when running the query **SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = 1792 AND meta_key = 'xTraData';**

[image]

And i made sure that **$postID** was returning **1792** and it is.

I was thinking it would return a **0** or **1**...

Comment: You need to _fetch_ from the result resource, which _does_ include a row.  `if ($result) { $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); print_r($row); }`

Comment: It won't return a 0 or 1 unless it was an insert or update query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`, possibly like so:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['postID'];
}
```

---

Don't use [`ext/mysql`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  Use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Comment: i get **<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function mysql_fethc_assoc()**

Comment: @StealthRT don't copy and paste code without reading it.  Typo corrected